# Mean.io application is throwing error with forever

Tags: gulp, forever, ubuntu-11.10, mean.io

I am working on a mean.io application. I am trying to run this application on Ubuntu shell  with forever module of node but it is throwing an error

```
"util.js:756
throw new TypeError('The super constructor to `inherits` must not ' +
^: The super constructor to `inherits` must not be null or undefined.
at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:756:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js:142:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/index.js:14:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
```

"

Can anyone help on this what is the actual issue,how i can resolve this error.

Comment: i am running this command for starting the application "forever gulp production" and then it throws the application mentioned above. When i run this application normally with gulp command "gulp production"  it is working fine.

Comment: I dont know why some one has down voted it without any reason

Answer (score 16):

I have faced the same issue. It was due to using Redistore with "express" parameter

```
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
```

finally I fixed it using a session as parameter.

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem as well.