# Issue with gulp trying to run an example - 'The super constructor to `inherits` must not be null or undefined.'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-http-proxy, nvm

I'm trying to run an [example](https://github.com/dqdinh/react-flux-coffeescript-browserify-gulp-demo), but I'm getting the following error when I try to gulp. I'm pretty new to node, so any direction or help would be very appreciated. The install went without any issues, seemingly.

```
$ nvm exec 4.2.2 gulp
Running node v4.2.2 (npm v2.14.7)
util.js:756
    throw new TypeError('The super constructor to `inherits` must not ' +
    ^

TypeError: The super constructor to `inherits` must not be null or undefined.
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:756:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([working directory path]/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:108:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([working directory path]/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
```

It seems this issue has come up in different contexts before but was unanswered:

1) [Mean.io application is throwing error with forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260433/mean-io-application-is-throwing-error-with-forever)

2) https://github.com/rajaraodv/rabbitpubsub/issues/4

Seems to be a fairly recent issue and it seems to not have to do with http-proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with an older version of browser-sync. Once that was updated, this started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try an older version of Node.  The example's `package.json` specifies Node 0.10 in the `engines` section, which suggests the initial code may have been written for that version.